# Unit testing C# implementation with F#-based testing tools

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing, f#, c#-to-f#

Outside of things syntactical, are there scenarios where it would be advantageous to write unit tests using F# for Greenfield C# code?

Here's a scenario:

1. You're in a team where all
   developers are C# 2.0-only, slowly
   learning about LINQ and lambdas.
2. They don't cover a single line with
   unit tests, which would place unit
   tests in F# at rarefied heights.
3. Unit testing is a choice and
   responsibility of the developer who
   is creating code.
4. If unit tests break, and the dev who
   wrote them is not on hand, the tests
   will be simply thrown away if they
   are hard to understand.
5. Main requirement here is to create
   production code in C#.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The fact that unit test snippets can easily be executed in F# Interactive is another possible advantage of testing with F#.

That said, it sounds like for this particular scenario/organization, it might be enough work trying to get anyone to write/execute unit tests, so it may be better to just start with some C# unit tests and focus on getting the 'unit tests are good/useful' culture instilled first.

Comment: Already writing unit tests in C#, and working on the culture.

Comment: @GregC - you can also experiment with C# code using Mono's CsharpRepl: http://www.mono-project.com/CsharpRepl it works great (complete support for the full language, unlike the Visual Studio Immediate Window which for example doesn't support LINQ expressions) and I keep the GUI version of the shell open at all times while doing C# development.

Answer (score 1):

I have found writing tests in FsUnit ( which is just a wrapper over nunit ) to be great and also the readability is good as well. ( for example you don't have to Pascal the test name. It can be a normal sentence. )

But like Brian says, in your case, you are better off starting with C# for the unit tests and then see how things go.

Comment: These are "things syntactical."